# rendering 2 components in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I stuck on one problem in my project I use 2 different components one is a card and second is a chart and i show the API data on that component but when I rendering both components it will be override to each other how I can solve this problem

```
render() {
    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
            {
                this.state.data.map((item, index) => {
                    return <div key={index} style={{ width: "300px" }}>
                        <Cards value={item} title={item.bikeId} time={item.timeStamp} />
                        <Speedometer speed={item.speed} />
                    </div>
                })
            }
        </div>        
    )
}
```

card and speedometer are two different components it will be created based on API response

Comment: Explain what you mean by "override" each other. This looks fine, but you could have styles that are making only one show - or maybe the width is too small

Comment: more explanation needed to answer this. Like from where you are fetching data and where you are passing props

Comment: Exactly, nothing seems to be overridden. If you’re using redux tools, you should be able to inspect your components and check if they’re actually rendered or not.

Comment: I fetching data from API and both components I pass different API objects. Components are automatically created according to for loop which I have written. So when I add both components for rendering they both are overlapping each other.

Answer (score 0):

By Overriding, if you mean the components are overlapping on one another, that might probably a CSS issue, try putting a `<br>` between both the components.

or

try increasing the width to 100% and remove that 300px